# Apache Reverse Proxy Unescapes URL

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I am running Apache 2.2.15 as a reverse proxy in my DMZ.  I have an application on the internal network that I make available on the Internet for staff to use by going through the reverse proxy.

As part of this application staff can see messages with PDF attachments.  Internal staff (who don't have to go through the reverse proxy) can download these PDFs just fine.  External staff can't.

This is what I see in the Apache logs on the application server.

```
172.20.0.9 - - [04/Dec/2014:08:48:21 +1300] "GET /application/home/getAttachment/MTE7Y3lzdGljIGZpYnJvc2lzLnBkZg%3D%3D HTTP/1.1" 200 88090
10.0.0.2 - - [04/Dec/2014:08:48:27 +1300] "GET /application/home/getAttachment/MTE7Y3lzdGljIGZpYnJvc2lzLnBkZg== HTTP/1.0" 400 -
```

The first request was from an internal user who successfully downloaded the PDF file.  The second comes from the reverse proxy in the DMZ.  Note how it has unescaped the "%3D%3D" at the end of the URL to "==".

There are a couple of things I'm doing in the reverse proxy.  First if someone tries to go to the root directory, a Rewrite rule sends them to the application directory.

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^/$ /application/ [NE,R]
  </IfModule>
```

The other relevant part of the config is the reverse proxy part.

```
  <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
   RequestHeader set Front-End-Https "On"
   SSLProxyEngine on
   SetEnv           force-proxy-request-1.0 1
   SetEnv           proxy-nokeepalive       1
   SetEnv proxy-initial-not-pooled 1

   # Reverse Proxy
   ProxyPass /application https://server.internal.lan/application
   ProxyPassReverse /application https://server.internal.lan/application
  </IfModule>
```

Can anyone tell me how to stop unescaping those URLs?

Thanks

David

Answer (score 0):

The [NE] flag in your rewrite rule is setting it to No Escape.  Try changing it to [B] to escape back references.

Comment: Hi Michael.  Thanks for the reply.  I made that change and restarted apache, but it doesn't seem to have made a difference.  Fortunately the application developer got me to modify a php config file and made "=" allowable in the url.  I hope it isn't going to cause any security problems.